# SignaturePad for Xamarin.Forms 2.2

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

After I upgraded to `Xamarin.Forms (v2.2)` I cannot use `SignaturePad.Xamarin.Forms.PCL` anymore, as it is not supported on `Android` anymore, and I cannot find a `SignaturePad`. 
So do anyone in here know to a `SignaturePad` based on `Skiasharp`? Or do I have to rewrite [`SignaturePad from Xamarin`](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signature-pad) to `Android` and `UWP`, as I think `iOS` is still supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the maintainer of that library to update using the latest Android Support Libraries(Even if it says it supports >= 1.5, it does not).

File an issue to their Github here or fork it yourself and make the changes: https://github.com/nate84/acr-xamarin-forms

Otherwise this will not be supported in the latest stable Xamarin.Forms as 2.2+ has a hard dependency on:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/

Dependencies:

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)
```

If the author has abandoned the project, I would recommend using our SignaturePad code or forking their existing project and maintaining it.

https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad

Comment: I would like to use SignaturePad from Xamarin, but it is not supported in UWP :(